# Operation on column based on column name pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a function only on one column based on its name.
For instance, I would like to do something like that

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4), index=dates, columns=list('ABCD'))
df['A']*10
df['B']*5
```

And obviously get df with the column A multiply by 10 and B multiply by 5.
The apply method work on the all dataframe. How to manage to do this only on one column ?

I'm sure it's a dumb question but I don't find answer ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`mul`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5tqvL4LjLAhWCQJoKHc94BXUQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.mul.html&usg=AFQjCNFD6MbVHE-wH4xhjKPMLqi3v-Og8A&sig2=beBj5rPyGcdQGbu5G9fdug&bvm=bv.116573086,d.bGs) method:

```
np.random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
df['A'] = df['A'].mul(10)
```

Example for original dataframe:

```
In [17]: df.A.mul(10)
Out[17]:
0    13.315865
1     6.213360
2     0.042914
3    -9.650657
4   -11.366022
5   -19.777283
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

It's faster then usual `*`:

```
In [18]: %timeit df.A.mul(10)
10000 loops, best of 3: 45.9 us per loop

In [19]: %timeit df.A * 10
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.8 us per loop
```

Comment: Great thanks ! In fact my problem was that my data was not float but string :D So I do df['A']*10**7 I get 10**7 letter... :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to reassign the operation to the column, i.e.:

```
df['A'] = df['A']*10
```

So if `df` is:

```
          A         B         C         D
0  0.413751 -0.484915 -0.559226 -0.522385
1 -0.889737 -1.000377 -0.442455  1.028374
2  0.038178  0.904601 -0.155169  0.152253
3  0.806682  1.119178  0.626849  2.069546
4  0.175276 -1.100351  1.556018 -0.231201
5  3.006512  1.046269  0.134351  1.157927
```

applying:

```
df['A'] = df['A']*10
df['B'] = df['B']*5
```

returns:

```
           A         B         C         D
0   4.137510 -2.424573 -0.559226 -0.522385
1  -8.897369 -5.001884 -0.442455  1.028374
2   0.381776  4.523004 -0.155169  0.152253
3   8.066817  5.595892  0.626849  2.069546
4   1.752762 -5.501753  1.556018 -0.231201
5  30.065124  5.231344  0.134351  1.157927
```

Comment: Thanks work fine in fact. I worked with string it's why this method didn't work ><